# How to upgrade bootstrap code for website to higher version?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have my website's html code written by following bootstrap 3.3.6 claases. Now I want to use the features of bootstrap 3.3.7 but it's not straight forward to just change the version of the bootstrap. What's the best way to do this upgrade? Do I need to write all the code again following bootstrap 3.3.7 standards?

Comment: Looking at the [3.3.7 change log](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v3.3.7), the only changes are bug fixes. You wouldn't have to change _any_ of your code. What makes you think it _"it's not straight forward to just change the version of the bootstrap"_?

Comment: just change the version of files its that much straight forward, the previous classes will stay there where they were and if you want to use new classes just amend them.
If you have previously files included try linking he cdn code there to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

the best upgrade to a new version is removes the url of old version and add the new url of a new version . for more help go to NPM documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--add your css file  here -->
<!--you must add the jQuery library here before the url of bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: i used npm to install not cdn

Comment: Then in addition to making the changes @Eng_Farghly suggested, you will also need to update your Bootstrap NPM package: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

Comment: @ventaur  I am so sorry ,  i don't have enough information about NPM

Comment: The OP should be able to figure out updating the package, but you could include this link in your answer for additional help. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update